# How can I show a message box with two buttons?

Tags: vbscript

How can I show a message box with two buttons (For example: `"on"`, `"off"`)?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
result = MsgBox ("Yes or No?", vbYesNo, "Yes No Example")

Select Case result
Case vbYes
    MsgBox("You chose Yes")
Case vbNo
    MsgBox("You chose No")
End Select
```

To add an icon:

```
result = MsgBox ("Yes or No?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Yes No Example")
```

Other icon options:

```
vbCritical or vbExclamation
```

Comment: Can I change the word on the button from yes to other string?

Comment: No, but as JohnFx suggested, you could rephrase the statement in your message box so that the "Yes" and "No" options would work.

Answer (score 5):

The [VBScript Messagebox](http://www.w3schools.com/VBScript/func_msgbox.asp) is fairly limited as to the labels you can apply to the buttons, your choices are pretty much limited to:

- OK
- Cancel
- Retry
- Abort
- Ignore
- Yes
- No

So you are going to have to build your own form if you want "ON"/"OFF"

Better yet, why not rephrase the prompt in the box so one of the above options works.

For example:

```
Do you want the light on? 
[Yes] [No]
```

And for God's sake **don't** do one of these UI monstrosities!

```
Switch setting? (Click "yes" for ON and "No" for Off)
[Yes] [No]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember - if you set the buttons to `vbOkOnly` - it will **always** return 1.

So you can't decide if a user clicked on the close or the OK button. You just have to add a `vbOk` option.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be done. [MsgBox](http://www.w3schools.com/VBScript/func_msgbox.asp) buttons can only have specific values.
You'll have to roll your own form for this.

To create a MsgBox with two options (Yes/No):

```
MsgBox("Some Text", vbYesNo)
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, I found it elsewhere on the web...this is no way my work ! :)

```
    Option Explicit
' Import
Private Declare Function GetCurrentThreadId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Private Declare Function SetDlgItemText Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetDlgItemTextA" _
    (ByVal hDlg As Long, _
     ByVal nIDDlgItem As Long, _
     ByVal lpString As String) As Long

Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" _
    (ByVal idHook As Long, _
     ByVal lpfn As Long, _
     ByVal hmod As Long, _
     ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

' Handle to the Hook procedure
Private hHook As Long

' Hook type
Private Const WH_CBT = 5
Private Const HCBT_ACTIVATE = 5

' Constants
Public Const IDOK = 1
Public Const IDCANCEL = 2
Public Const IDABORT = 3
Public Const IDRETRY = 4
Public Const IDIGNORE = 5
Public Const IDYES = 6
Public Const IDNO = 7

Public Sub MsgBoxSmile()
    ' Set Hook
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, _
                             AddressOf MsgBoxHookProc, _
                             0, _
                             GetCurrentThreadId)

    ' Run MessageBox
    MsgBox "Smiling Message Box", vbYesNo, "Message Box Hooking"
End Sub

Private Function MsgBoxHookProc(ByVal lMsg As Long, _
                                ByVal wParam As Long, _
                                ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

    If lMsg = HCBT_ACTIVATE Then
        SetDlgItemText wParam, IDYES, "Yes   :-)"
        SetDlgItemText wParam, IDNO, "No   :-("

        ' Release the Hook
        UnhookWindowsHookEx hHook
    End If

    MsgBoxHookProc = False
End Function
```

Comment: You can't do Windows API calls like that in VBScript. This code is either VBA or VB6

Answer (score 0):

```
msgbox ("Message goes here",0+16,"Title goes here")
```

if the user is supposed to make a decision the variable can be added like this.

```
variable=msgbox ("Message goes here",0+16,"Title goes here")
```

The numbers in the middle vary what the message box looks like.
Here is the list

0 - ok button only

1 - ok and cancel

2 - abort, retry and ignore

3 - yes no and cancel

4 - yes and no

5 - retry and cancel

TO CHANGE THE SYMBOL (RIGHT NUMBER)

16 - critical message icon

32 - warning icon

48 - warning message

64 - info message

DEFAULT BUTTON

0 = vbDefaultButton1 - First button is default

256 = vbDefaultButton2 - Second button is default

512 = vbDefaultButton3 - Third button is default

768 = vbDefaultButton4 - Fourth button is default

SYSTEM MODAL

4096 = System modal, alert will be on top of all applications

Note: There are some extra numbers. You just have to add them to the numbers already there like

```
msgbox("Hello World", 0+16+0+4096)
```

> from https://www.instructables.com/id/The-Ultimate-VBS-Tutorial/

Answer (score -1):

I did

```
msgbox "TEXT HERE",3,"TITLE HERE"
If Yes=true then
(result)

else
msgbox "Closing..."
```

Comment: MsgBox should be called as a function; where does the Yes come from? The upvoter should be ashamed.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to make Custom Dialog boxes in 2021 that are just as easy as Msgboxes! Note this is for VB, not VB script.

[image: Custom Dialog]

First make a new form using the dialog box template. It includes two boxes already of which you can change the names/text:

[image: New Form]

Then back in your main code put this, where "Dialog1" is the name of your new dialog. This allows you to treat this form as a msgbox with just one line of code:

```
Dim dialogInstance As New Dialog1
Dim result As dialogResult = dialogInstance.ShowDialog()
```

The variable "result" will behave like a traditional OK/Cancel msgbox exactly like the options above, but will display your custom text on the buttons. From here you can add custom pictures to your msgbox and more!

Comment: The question is for VBScript. Your answer is for VB (Visual Basic). They're very different animals.