# Asp.Net MessageBox and AnswerBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, messagebox

I am new to Asp.Net.
I've found somewhere how to make in Asp.net/Javascript a MessageBox:

```
public static void Show(String str,Page pg, Object obj)
{
  string s = "<SCRIPT language='javascript'>alert('" + str.Replace("\r\n", "\\n").Replace("'", "`") + "'); </SCRIPT>";
  Type cstype = obj.GetType();
  ClientScriptManager cs = pg.ClientScript;
  cs.RegisterClientScriptBlock(cstype, s, s.ToString());
}
```

So the question is: is there a way (using a similar code) to get an answerBox (yes/No) displaying a message a getting the yes/No answer?
thanx in advance

Comment: You can use `confirm`. However, thats not yes/no but ok/cancel. You either need to use that or use [VBScript and `msgbox`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062401/vb-script-how-to-create-msgbox-with-two-buttons).

Comment: As I said below thanx that works but how to get the Yes/No answer inside the function? I'd like something like: bool AnswerBox(String str) {...};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - use `confirm` instead of `alert` in your script.  See for example http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Javascript example:

```
(function () {
  var r = confirm("OK or Cancel ?");
  if (r == true) {
    alert("You pressed OK!");
  } else {
    alert("You pressed Cancel!");
  }
})();
```

Comment: Wow that was fast!!! thanx a lot it worked for showing the YES/NO answer box but since I don't know javascript I don't know how to get the answer as showed in the link you provided. Is there a way to do this keeping all the code inside the messagebox function? Also a OnConfirmation additiona function will do though...