# How do I add to a to VBS file command

Tags: vbscript

I have the following VBScript to which I'm trying to add to, but I need help in how to do it.

At present I have the script below that asks for the file name I want it to be called and then creates a folder and moves of which ok.

What I'm trying to add is after the folder is created I need a command box with the YES/NO option and if I click YES I need the file moved to C:\DOCUMENTS\A  and if NO I need it moved to C:\DOCUMENTS\B.

Once I've clicked YES or NO and it has moved the folder I need to open Folder A or B to view.

Any Ideas?

```
Option Explicit

Const strDLFolder = "C:\Downloads"
Dim objFSO, objWShell, objDLFolder, strNewFolder, objFile

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objWShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")


If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strDLFolder) Then objFSO.CreateFolder(strDLFolder)
objWShell.CurrentDirectory = strDLFolder
Set objDLFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDLFolder)
If objDLFolder.Files.Count = 0 Then WScript.Quit

Do
    Err.Clear
    strNewFolder = InputBox("Folder Name", vbLf & "Enter the name of the folder to be created:")
    If strNewFolder = False Then WScript.Quit
    On Error Resume Next
    objFSO.CreateFolder strNewFolder
Loop While Err.Number <> 0 Or Not objFSO.FolderExists(strNewFolder)

On Error Goto 0
For Each objFile In objDLFolder.Files
    objFSO.MoveFile objFile.Name, strNewFolder & "\"
Next

objWShell.Popup "All files moved.", 0, "Done", vbInformation Or vbSystemModal Or &h00040000&
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. (Saying *I'm trying* is not making an effort.) Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. If you can't make that effort, hire a contractor and pay them to do it for you. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I show a message box with two buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3062401/how-can-i-show-a-message-box-with-two-buttons)